# Groovy List Parameter issues : += does not work but .add() does

Tags: groovy

```
public updateList(lst) {
  lst += "a"
}

List lst = []
updateList(lst)
println(lst)
```

This prints an empty list. However;

```
public updateList(lst) {
  lst.add("a")
}

List lst = []
updateList(lst)
println(lst)
```

, will print "a" as desired.

I always assumed += was the same as .add(), but obviously not. I assume += is creating a new List, whereas .add() only updated the existing List?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first method calls `plus` on the `lst` variable

As we can see [from the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#plus(T)) this will:

> Create a collection as a union of a
>   Collection and an Object.

So a new collection will be returned, and the original `lst` (outside the scope of this method) will be unchanged.  (Obviously, inside this method's scope, lst will be a new list with one element)

This can be seen by printing out the result of the `updateList` method:

```
public updateList(lst) {
  lst += "a"  // calls plus, creates a new list, and returns this new list.
              // lst (outside the context of this method) is unmodified
}

List lst = []
println( updateList(lst) )
```

If you call `add`, then you call the [standard java add method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)).

```
public updateList(lst) {
  lst.add "a"
}
```

So the original `lst` is modified

An alternative to `add` would be to use the `leftShift` operator:

```
public updateList(lst) {
  lst << "a"
}
```

Which calls add behind the scenes: (code from Groovy trunk source)

```
public static <T> Collection<T> leftShift(Collection<T> self, T value) {
    self.add(value);
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That's why many languages do not allow operator overloading. Sure `lst + elt` and `lst << elt` looks kinda cool, but it's not particularly clear.

Comment: I would expect the syntax `lst += "a"` to mean that the element "a" is being added in-place to the list `lst`, i.e. `lst = lst + "a"`, but the semantics for this (Codehaus)Groovy syntax is indeed confusing. Taking seriously the JSR (241) to standardize Groovy semantics after open public discussions would've prevented these highly unintuitive corner cases.